# How to enable the bribing of democracies

Tags: freeciv

By default, Freeciv's democracy is an unbribable form of government. Units belonging to a democracy cannot be bribed, and enemy diplomats/spies cannot incite revolts in cities belonging to a democracy. How do I turn democracy into a form of government that can be bribed (similar to despotism, monarchy, republic, and communism)?